# Dataweave: filtering on a value in a nested array

Tags: filter, dataweave, mulesoft

I am looking for a solution to filter an object in a nested array in data weave. I have found a solution that does the job but it looks very cumbersome.

This is my input array:

```
var inputMessage = [
    {
    "name": "ben",
    "lastName": "TEST1",
    "hobby": [{
        id: 1,
        name: "football",
        isDeleted: false
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "hockey",
        isDeleted: false
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "Bart",
    "lastName": "TEST2",
    "hobby": [{
        id: 1,
        name: "football",
        isDeleted: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "hockey",
        isDeleted: false
    }
    ]
    }
]
```

This is the output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ben",
    "lastName": "TEST1",
    "hobby": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "football",
        "isDeleted": false
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "hockey",
        "isDeleted": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you see the person object with "Bart" is completely removed. This is done because one of the hobbies of Bart has an isDeleted: true. So when one of a person's hobbies has an is deleted: true then that person's object must be removed.

This is what I have created myself:

```
output application/json
---
(input message map ($ map object ((value, key, index) -> 
if((key ~= "hobby" and (value reduce ((item, acc = []) -> acc + item.isDeleted ) contains(true)))) 
{"hobby": "remove"} 
else 
{(key):value}))) 
filter $.hobby != "remove"
```

Anybody has an idea or solution for an easier more gentle way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below. I hope this helps.

Input:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ben",
    "lastName": "TEST1",
    "hobby": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "football",
        "isDeleted": false
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "hockey",
        "isDeleted": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Bart",
    "lastName": "TEST2",
    "hobby": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "football",
        "isDeleted": true
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "hockey",
        "isDeleted": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

DataWeave Script1:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload filter ($.hobby filter $.isDeleted == true) == [] map {
    name: $.name,
    lastName: $.lastName,
    hobby: $.hobby
}
```

Dataweave Script2:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload filter ((item, index) -> not ((item.hobby filter $.isDeleted == true) != [])) map {
    name: $.name,
    lastName: $.lastName,
    hobby: $.hobby filter $.isDeleted == false
} filter $.hobby != "remove"
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ben",
    "lastName": "TEST1",
    "hobby": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "football",
        "isDeleted": false
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "hockey",
        "isDeleted": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You can reduce it a bit by removing the comparison to `true`, because `isDeleted` already contains a `true` or `false` value. Unless it can hold a different value.

Comment: Yes thanks very much and you can also remove the map part because that doesn't change the output.